# Best way to save instance state

Tags: android

What is the lesser boiler-plate code to save the state on configuration change.

I want something like an annotation processor.

Comment: Lesser bioler-plate than what?

Comment: Then normal Android implementation. :D Thanks for down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IcePick. 
https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick

It is very simple to use.

```
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
  @State 
  String username; // This will be automatically saved and restored

  @Override 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override 
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Icepick.saveInstanceState(this, outState);
  }

  // You can put the calls to Icepick into a BaseActivity
  // All Activities extending BaseActivity automatically have state saved/restored
}
```

Just use the @State notation.